# weird join in php

Tags: php, mysql, join

Okay so I'm not a novice to PHP nor am I a novice to MySQL or joins...  But what I have to do, i'm not completely sure it's possible without running a foreach to inject the data into my current array...

So, I have a join that is like so:

```
SELECT `priorities`.`pri_name`, `agent_status`.`sta_title`, `specializations`.`spec_title`, `agents`.*
FROM (`agents`)
JOIN `priorities` ON `priorities`.`id` = `agents`.`priority`
JOIN `agent_status` ON `agent_status`.`s_id` = `agents`.`user_status`
JOIN `Specializations` ON `specializations`.`id` = `agents`.`Specialization`
WHERE `agents`.`id` =  '4';
```

Now, I need to add one more join to this which under normal circumstances wouldn't be an issue.  But what I need to figure out, is how in this single query can i create a join on the same table but a different record.

So basically I'd need to select is the f_name, l_name of the 2nd record where the id is the same as the pid of the initial selected record...  so something like adding into my select:

```
agents.f_name AS pf_name, agents.l_name AS pl_name
```

then having something like...

```
JOIN('agents' ON agents.id = agents.p_id
```

or something like that...

Comment: Have you ever pondered about using views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a self-join with aliases for this. As an example consider the following code:

```
SELECT
   a.*, b.*
FROM
   table AS a
   JOIN table as b
WHERE
   a.id = b.pid
```

With this code example you should be able to apply this to your existing query.

In your existing query you should change the prefix `agents` for the references to fields of the agents table with the alias you use for the table, so `agents`.`priority` should become alias.priority.

Comment: Beautiful..  this works like a charm thanks much for the self-join technique! I'll select your answer momentarily.

Answer (score 1):

You can use table aliases and join the same table as many time as you need (certainly, no more than maximum allowed join number):

```
FROM agents a1
JOIN agents a2 ON ([condition])
JOIN agents a3 ON ([condition])
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is to alias the second reference to the `agents` table with a different name. In my example, I'll use `a2` as the alias name.

```
SELECT ..., a2.f_name AS pf_name, a2.l_name AS pl_name
...
JOIN agents a2
    ON agents.p_id = a2.id
...
```